# how to create slider in the wordpress which show posts?

Tags: wordpress

I search many slider for post to show.I want to create slider exact as 
http://kent.co.in/   features slider which show the post.I am using carousel slider plugin but the expected output is not showing.Thanks

Comment: And if you want to do it with plugin, you can use [this one](https://wordpress.org/plugins/carousel-horizontal-posts-content-slider/)

Comment: thanks....I tried hard but i didn't get the post slider.It showing blank space

Answer (score 0):

You can pass your dynamic post to your slider image.

1. make an slider category for post
2. Set featured image with each slider post.
3. and get post filter by slider category
4. and pass it to the your slider imagees

   ```
   // The Query
   $the_query = new WP_Query( 'cat=4' );   // lets suppose slider category id is 4
   // The Loop
   if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
       echo '<ul>';
       while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {

           echo 'your post thumbnail go here';
       }
       echo '</ul>';
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

1. Install and activate Soliloquy Slider plugin.
2. Create an image slider with Soliloquy.
3. Copy the template tag from Soliloquy Slider Code widget.
4. Edit the theme's template file and paste the template tag.
5. Click on the save button.

   for more info: https://www.cosmicenergy.in/